# Inject a service into another service in the same module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a ChatService A that depends upon an interface.

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NGXLogger } from 'ngx-logger';
import { TokenHttpService } from '@lib/interfaces';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('TokenHttpService') private tokenFetchService: TokenHttpService,
    private logger: NGXLogger
  ) {
    this.logger.debug('Confirmed ctor for ChatService called');
  }
}
```

I have a HttpService B that implements the TokenHttpService interface.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CoreDataService } from '@app/core/async-services/http/core.data';
import { TokenHttpService } from 'he-common';
import { NGXLogger } from 'ngx-logger';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService implements TokenHttpService {
  constructor(
    private _coreDataService: CoreDataService,
    private logger: NGXLogger
  ) {
       this.logger.debug("Confirmed ctor for HttpService called");
    }
}
```

Then I try to combine them both in MessagingModule C

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { MessagingPage } from './messaging.page';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ChatService } from 'my-common-lib';
import { SharedModule } from '@app/shared';
import { HttpService } from '@app/core/async-services/http/versioned/http';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MessagingPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [MessagingPage],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'TokenHttpService', useValue: HttpService },
    { provide: ChatService, deps: ['TokenHttpService'] }
  ]
})
export class MessagingPageModule {}
```

If I'm not mistaken this code should work like this: C attempts to construct A and is told it needs B, B is provided to the module as well so it should provide B to A so that it can be constructed and used in component D.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from 'he-common';
import { NGXLogger } from 'ngx-logger';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-messaging',
  templateUrl: './messaging.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messaging.page.scss']
})
export class MessagingPage {

  constructor(
    private ChatService: ChatService,
    private logger: NGXLogger
  ) {
    // This line logs undefined.
    this.logger.debug(this.twilioChatService);
  }
}
```

How can I provide the TokenHttpService B to Service A? Can I do it in the same module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my problems were:

1. I needed to use the `useClass` property instead of the `useValue` property. `useClass` expects a constructor (or factory function) while the `useValue` property expects a simple object.
2. In the `deps` section you are basically overriding what values you want to pass into the constructor for the service. So, in my case, I had the `'TokenHttpService'` injected but no logger, so my service threw an error when it tried to call `this.logger.debug`. After adding `NGXLogger` to the `deps` array the service worked flawlessly.

Here's my final providers array:

```js
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'TokenHttpService',
      useClass: HttpService
    },
    {
      provide: ChatService,
      deps: ['TokenHttpService', NGXLogger],
      useClass: ChatService
    }
  ]
```